# Win32Exception caught by Application.ThreadException - missing own code

Tags: .net, winforms, exception

I am getting an unhandled exception somewhere in the Ribbon of the UltraToolbarsManager (Infragistics). But that is not the relevant part I want to ask here. The question I have is: why don't I see any methods of my application in the stack trace? The stack trace shows only Infragistics and Windows Forms modules.

The reproduction scenario is very rare, but the few times it has been seen was always when the machine was going to suspend mode. The exception is handled by the Application.ThreadException event handler and I have had no chance to catch from a different location (the form is loaded and run with Applicatioin.Run()).

Here are the exception details:

```
The handle is invalid
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Stack Trace:
   bei System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)
        bei System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)
        bei System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Point upperLeftSource, Point upperLeftDestination, Size blockRegionSize)
        bei Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.CaptureOldImage(UIElement element)
        bei Infragistics.Win.TransitionInfo..ctor(UIElement element, Transition transition, TransitionSettings settings)
        bei Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.InitiateTransition(TransitionSettings settings, Transition transition, UIElement element)
        bei Infragistics.Win.UIElement.InitiateTransition(TransitionSettings settings, UIElementTransitionType transitionType)
        bei Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.RibbonGroupUIElement.OnMouseLeave()
        bei Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.ElementEntered(UIElement element, Boolean triggerMouseLeavesOnly)
        bei Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.SyncMouseEntered(Boolean triggerMouseLeavesOnly, UIElementInputType inputType, Boolean ignoreLastElementEntered)
        bei Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.ProcessMouseLeave(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        bei Infragistics.Win.Utilities.ProcessEvent(Control control, ProcessEvent eventToProcess, EventArgs e)
        bei Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        bei Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsDockArea.OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseLeave(Message& m)
        bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
        bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
        bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
        bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Is there a way to catch the exception otherwise than from the Application.ThreadException event, where I may see more details?

The exception is handled on the same thread as the form gets created, so I suppose that it is not caused by another thread modifying the UI.

I would appreciate any help or hints where to look at.

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: Very difficult to say. Seems triggered when the mouse exit from a ribbon Group (MouseLeave event). A malformed tooltip text or something? It is just a guess.

Comment: Indeeed, that was also my first thought and I tried reproducing it. But in a different case the initial method was not a MouseLeave but a Paint event.

Comment: This kind of exception occurs when you leak window handles.  With the kaboom happening when your program has consumed 10,000 of them and Windows no longer willing to let you create another.  A pretty common bug in Winforms programming, using Controls.Clear() or Controls.Remove/At() without disposing the control is a good way to cause a permanent leak.  You can diagnose it with Task Manager, View + Select Colums, tick USER32 Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/d55d7789-0454-461c-bb3a-62639c394603/

On Windows 8 the lock screen comes in front of the lock screen and the handle gets invalid before System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen() can do it's job.

Thanks for listening and thanks Steve for bringing me back to my first thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a discussion at the Infragistics Forums about the very same behavior. It could be found here: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/79895/403562.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that. This issue will be fix by Infragistics very soon. The issue is currently in the final stages of its verification, and once it is publicly available your forum post will be updated accordingly.